# Проверьте пожалуйста логику базы данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Я пишу програмку для ЖКХ, где есть дома, жители и платёжки за комуналку. (Думаю все имеют представление что это и как). Сейчас программирую раздел баланса жителей, начисление им платёжек и оплаты услуг.
Прошу, кому интересно, или кто уже делал подобое, проверить и дать оценку структуры базы в этом вопросе.
Исходные данные:

Есть пользователи, у них есть свой баланс. Они платят за услуги (увеличивая баланс). Им начисляются платёжки за оплату - уменьшается баланс. Платить они могут любой суммой, а платёжка за коммуналку состоит из нескольких услуг.

Я проектирую без фиксированного остатка баланса. То есть баланс всегда считается динамически, что бы при корректировках не пересчитывать баланс. То есть баланс формируется из начального остатка, всех оплат жителя и всех начислений.

Я решил сделать две основные таблицы:
Таблица оплат и таблица начислений  (картинка максимальна упрощена для простоты понимания смысла)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица Platezhka - содержит все сформированные квитанции за каждый период, дополнительная таблица Uslugi Platezjki содержит список услуг в платёжке, и привязывается к id платежки.

Таким образом если просумировать оплаты и вычесть сумму услуг то получим конечный баланс. Изменения в платёжках сразу обновят баланс, и так же можно будет вытащить отдельно платёжки для отображения за любой период.

Есть какие-то замечания/предложения?

Comment: *Я решил сделать две основные таблицы: Таблица оплат и таблица начислений* Нафига? Операция-то одна и та же - движение денежных средств на счёте клиента. *Есть какие-то замечания/предложения?* Забыть об "изменениях в платёжках". Только корректировка платёжки путём ввода новой записи с новым состоянием платёжки. Т.е. БД должна проектироваться только на INSERT и SELECT, никаких UPDATE и DELETE.

Comment: Получается, что если объединить оплаты жителей и начисления в одной таблице "финансы", то что бы брать просто отдельные начисления - нужно будет постоянно смотреть эту таблицу. К тому же если у начисления (если несколько услуг в платёжке) есть привязка к периоду к платёжке, то в таблице финансы нужно заводить поля, которые через одну операцию будут NULL. Это точно эффективно?

Comment: У тебя будет главная таблица - движения средств. На которую ссылаются два отдельных блока - блок начислений и блок платежей. Не, можешь и не делать такой объединяющей таблицы... никто не заставляет.